# Calculating based on date pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = ['2019-08-01', '2019-09-01', '2019-10-23', '2019-11-12', '2019-11-30']
c = [12, 0, 0, 0, 0]
d = [0, 23, 0, 0, 0]
e = [12, 24, 35, 0, 0]
f = [0, 0, 44, 56, 82]
g = [21, 22, 17, 75, 63]

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': a, 'Date': b, 'Unit_sold_8': c, 
                  'Unit_sold_9': d, 'Unit_sold_10': e, 'Unit_sold_11': f, 
                   'Unit_sold_12': g})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

I want to calculate average sales of each ID which are based on Date. For example, If ID's open date was on Sep, so the average sales of this ID would start on Sep. I tried `np.select` but I realized that this method would make my code super long.

```
col = df.columns

mask1 = (df['Date'] >= "08/01/2019") & (df['Date'] < "09/01/2019")
mask2 = (df['Date'] >= "09/01/2019") & (df['Date'] < "10/01/2019")
mask3 = (df['Date'] >= "10/01/2019") & (df['Date'] < "11/01/2019")
mask4 = (df['Date'] >= "11/01/2019") & (df['Date'] < "12/01/2019")
mask5 = (df['Date'] >= "12/01/2019")

condition2 = [mask1, mask2, mask3, mask4, mask5]
result2 = [df[col[2:]].mean(skipna = True, axis = 1),
          df[col[3:]].mean(skipna = True, axis = 1),
          df[col[4:]].mean(skipna = True, axis = 1),
          df[col[5:]].mean(skipna = True, axis = 1),
          df[col[6:]].mean(skipna = True, axis = 1)]
df.loc[:, 'Mean'] = np.select(condition2, result2, default = np.nan)
```

Are there any way faster to solve this problem? Especially when the time range is expanded (12 months, 24 months, .etc)

Comment: i'm looking at ur calculations - i get the mean for the first row been 9, but the next row 17.25? shouldnt it be 13.8?

Comment: Ah because in the second row, ID's open date is on Sep, so the mean value would include unit solds from 9 to 12 (including 0). In my example, the result of the second row = (23+ 24+ 0 +22)/4 = 17.25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it help you?

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
from dateutil import relativedelta


check_date = datetime.today()
df['n_months'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: relativedelta.relativedelta( check_date,x).months)
df['total'] = df.iloc[:,range(2,df.shape[1]-1)].sum(axis=1)
df['avg']  = df['total'] / df['n_months']

print(df)

   ID       Date  Unit_sold_8  ...  n_months  total    avg
0   1 2019-08-01           12  ...         5     45   9.00
1   2 2019-09-01            0  ...         4     69  17.25
2   3 2019-10-23            0  ...         3     96  32.00
3   4 2019-11-12            0  ...         2    131  65.50
4   5 2019-11-30            0  ...         2    145  72.50
```

Comment: Sorry, the result I need was already in the post, you can run and check it

Comment: I dont understand your code- if id -1 start on 2019-08-01 and the total is 51 how do you calculate the mean?

Comment: In the first row, mean of the first ID  = (12+0+12+0+21)/5. In your code you add 6 so it's not what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

```
M= df 
   #melt data to pull units as variables

 .melt(id_vars=['ID','Date'])

   #create temp variables to pull out Month from Date and Units

 .assign(Mth=lambda x: x['Date'].dt.month, 
         oda_detail = lambda x: x.variable.str.split('_').str[-1])
 .sort_values(['ID','Mth'])

  #keep only rows where the Mth is less than or equal to other detail

 .loc[lambda x : x['Mth'].astype(int).le(x['oda_detail'].astype(int))]

  #groupby and get the mean

 .groupby(['ID','Date'])['value'].mean()
 .reset_index()
 .drop(['ID','Date'],axis=1)
 .rename({'value':'Mean'},axis=1)
```

Join back to original dataframe:

```
pd.concat([df,M],axis=1)

ID  Date    Unit_sold_8 Unit_sold_9 Unit_sold_10    Unit_sold_11     
 Unit_sold_12   Mean
0   1   2019-08-01  12  0   12  0   21  9.00
1   2   2019-09-01  0   23  24  0   22  17.25
2   3   2019-10-23  0   0   35  44  17  32.00
3   4   2019-11-12  0   0   0   56  75  65.50
4   5   2019-11-30  0   0   0   82  63  72.50
```